# How to handle triggers with dependent objects?

Tags: apex, trigger, api, bestpractice

I have a problem regarding triggers on objects that effect other objects.

When a Contact is saved on Salesforce, in my case it also saves an Affiliation.

I have a trigger on each object that when either of these objects are saved, a call is made to an external service where the data is also processed and saved there. As Affiliations, Contacts and Accounts are dependent on each other (that is an Affiliation can't exist without the Contact and the Account) the Account and Contact need to be created before the Affiliation. I'm not sure how to guarantee that this will be the case.

So I have two solutions, one is to process each step of the process with callbacks. That is, in the Contact trigger, post a request to make my Contact externally, then when that returns have a callback that posts to make the Account externally and finally when that returns send a request to create the Affiliation.

There is an issue with this in that the requests will also fire off a result of the triggers I will have to have on the Account and Affiliation objects (as these objects can obviously be updated separately).

**My question for this solution is there a way to stop the triggers from firing off if I know that these objects are being saved as part of the Contact save process?**  I can manage this by making my external API resilient to multiple requests so it's not the end of the world if I have to do this I'm just looking for some insight on best practice.

My other solution involves making one big request to the external API in the Contact post save but I don't know how to ensure the Account and Affiliation are created and get all their data to bundle up for my request (without doing some sort of sleep or wait and I'm just very unsure about this). **So my question is here, is there an order of operations for the Account and Affiliations being created when I create or save a Contact?**

Any other thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Edit: I'm using Nonprofit Success Pack (NPSP).

Comment: You appear to be using either NPSP or EDA. Can you confirm that that's the case? ([edit] to add details).

Comment: All done, thanks.